# Copy column header if cell value below is 0

Tags: excel

This is an example of what I am working with:

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXnib.png)

The spreadsheet lists the export value to each country from each US state. I need to create a list for each state that shows which countries recieved 0 exports from that state. 
Something that looks like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlaZv.png)

I have tried to do an index match but that just gave me a #Value error. 
If anyone has suggestions on how to tackle this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are any "easy" way.. you need to do some work.

I would

- Take all the Countries and copy them. Then transpose them so they are
  column wise (see my column L). I removed the merged cells as it make it easier to apply formula.
- Then I will copy the counties 52 times (to match all the states) and add each state to the
  adjacent column (see my column K).

Then I will apply this formula (See my column M), where all 0 means that no value exist for the combination you are looking for. (example Alabama and Algeria gives 0):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$G$9,MATCH(K2,$A$3:$A$9,0),MATCH(L2,$B$1:$G$1,0)),0)
```

Where:

Return values: `INDEX($B$3:$G$9...` - is what we want to return (green area)

Row match: `...MATCH(K2,$A$3:$A$9,0)...`... is which row the return value should be located (blue area)

Column match: `...MATCH(L2,$B$1:$G$1,0)...`... is which column the return value should be located (yellow area)

Adjust these values to match your data (don't forget to make your reference absolute with  `$` signs.

Now you should have a easy table which you can filter from 0 (nothing in your dataset) and export values.

[image]